# Filenames in the apt cache directory

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb, filename

Why the packages in the directory

> /var/cache/apt/archives/

have names like:
*x11proto-damage-Dev_1%3a1.2.0-1_all.deb* where the "strange" in this case is "%3".
In fact, if I download it manually from the firefox the package has the name "normal".

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because the cache contains the URL specific scheme of representation characters, %3a is ASCII code 3A in hexadecimal, which is character ":" and if you query that installed package eg with command `dpkg -s x11proto-damage-dev | grep Version` you can see that it contains ":"

Version: 1:1.2.0-1

So indeed, that ":" is encoded as %3a ...

Comment: Thanks. But I do not understand why some symbols do not have the notation '%..' as for example '+'.

Comment: "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL." I understand! Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yes, there are rules of this encoding, it's hard to ask "why", because it was defined this way :) But it's nice that you figured out yourself too after the first comment, good work :)

Comment: Oops, I tried to upvote your second comment, but accidentally clicked the first one :p Well, nice self-education ^^